# Discrete series representation of SO(2,1)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Since so(2,1) is a noncompact Lie algebra, its unitary representations are all infinite-dimensional. Now, I have seen that the unitary representations of so(2,1) can be divided into three categories:

1. Discrete series - with a lowest or highest state satisfying $J_{\pm}|j,m\rangle = 0$, where $C|j,m\rangle = -j(j+1) |j,m\rangle$ ($C$ is the Casimir operator) and $J_3|j,m\rangle = m|j,m\rangle$. Also $J_\pm = J_1 \pm iJ_2$.
2. Principal series.
3. Complementary series.

For principal and complementary series, there is no lower or upper bound for the $m$ values. Now, I have seen in most books and literature that for the discrete series, $j$ only takes integer or half-integer values rather than continuum values which gives the name discrete series. However, I cannot find any reason why should $j,m$ only can have integer or half-integer values if there is a lower bound on the $m$ values.

In other words, starting with the assumption that there exists a lower or upper bound of the value $m$, how can we conclude that $j$ has to be discrete?

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669692/2451

Answer (score 1):

This is quite standard, see e.g. Harmonic Analysis of SL(2,R), Howe. Since the original question is from the physics forum, I also recommend personally the expository paper arXiv:2111.04591.

Starting from the assumption of quasi-simpleness that the Casimir's action is diagonalizable (i.e. semisimple), the vectors $|j,m\rangle$ are chosen as the joint eigenvectors of $J_0$ and $C$, then the matrix elements of $J_{\pm}$ can be fixed as functions of eigenvalues of $J_0$ and $C$.

For (half-)integer spin, the matrix elements of $J_{\pm}$ vanishes at certain $|j,m\rangle$, and this implies the representation is reducible, and the irreducible one from the quotient is of highest/lowest weight type.